# Right unitor in star-autonomous categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, vector-spaces, rigidity

**1.Context**
Let $(C, \otimes,  I, a, l,r)$ be a monoidal category. Here $r$ denotes the right unitor.
Suppose $S: C^{op} \xrightarrow{\sim} C$ is an equivalence of categories with inverse $S’$. Assume that there are bijections $\phi_{X,Y,Z}: \operatorname{Hom}_C(X \otimes Y,SZ) \xrightarrow{\sim} \operatorname{Hom}_C(X, S(Y \otimes Z))$ natural in $X,Y,Z$. This makes $C$ a star-autonomous category. Note that we do not assume that $S$ is a monoidal equivalence. For simplicity suppose that the associator $a$ is the identity and that $S$ and $S'$ are strict inverses.

Define the functor $⅋: C \times C \rightarrow C$ as the composite $C \times C \xrightarrow{\tau}C \times C \xrightarrow{(S',S')} C^{op} \times C^{op}= (C \times C)^{op}\xrightarrow{\otimes^{op}} C^{op}\xrightarrow{S} C$. Here $\tau$ denotes the functor that switches components, while $\otimes^{op}$ is the [opposite functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/opposite+category#opposite_functors) of the monoidal product $\otimes$.

**2.Question**
Does the equality $$\phi_{A ⅋ B,I,S'B \otimes S'A}(r_{A ⅋ B})=\operatorname{id_A} ⅋ \: \phi_{B,I,S'B}(r_B)$$ hold for any two objects $A,B \in C$?

In the monoidal category of finite dimensional vector spaces over a field with usual duality functor (and the choice of $\phi$ arising from the standard choice of coevaluation and evaluation for the rigid structure) the equality holds. This essentially follows from my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4459091/unitors-in-star-autonomous-categories) together with the fact that the left unitor is natural. For any other choice of $\phi$ that arises from a change of coevaluation/evaluation the equality remains true.
More precisely, we can scale each coevaluation $\text{coev}_X:k \rightarrow X^* \otimes X$ by a non-zero scalar $\lambda_X$. This scales any $\phi_{-,X,-}$ by $\lambda_X$. Then the equality still holds since both sides of the equation are scaled by $\lambda_I$.

I tried other examples (in particular non-rigid ones) – to no avail. What is a good place to look for counterexamples to the equality?
In particular, I realized that I don't know what the natural transformation $\phi_{X,Y,Z}: \operatorname{Hom}_C(X \otimes Y,SZ) \xrightarrow{\sim} \operatorname{Hom}_C(X, S(Y \otimes Z))$ looks like for many non-rigid, non-posetal star-autonomous categories (e.g. the category of sup-lattices, of coherence spaces, of phase spaces). Often I can show that the natural transformation exists, but getting my hands dirty proved rather difficult. Any help in that respect would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have an answer to the question as posed, but I think this is the wrong definition of $\ast$-autonomous category, essentially because of the counterexamples you mentioned in your answer to your other question.  (I have been meaning to fix the nLab page ever since I realized this, but never gotten around to it.)  The existence of such a $\phi$ is sufficient to give $C$ the *property* of being $\ast$-autonomous, as I believe was noted already in Barr's original paper, but it alone isn't a correct specification of the *structure* of $\ast$-autonomy.

Comment: To get a correct structure, you can either restrict $\phi$ to the case when $X$ is the unit, as in Definition C of Barr's paper on the [non-symmetric case](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/asymm.pdf), or keep the general $\phi$ but impose a "pentagon" axiom relating it to the associator.  I don't know of a published reference that does the latter for $\ast$-autonomous categories, but it appears in the more general context of Frobenius pseudomonoids in [this paper](https://www.irif.fr/~mellies/tensorial-logic/9-dialogue-categories-and-frobenius-monoids.pdf) by Mellies (Definition 9).

Comment: @MikeShulman: What do you mean by "To get a *correct structure*, you can either restrict $\phi$ to the case when $X$ is the unit […]"? I do not think, that you are  saying that if $C$ is a category in the sense of definition C in Barr's paper then the natural isomorphism is unique. That is again already false in the category of finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: Besides, if my definition (essentially taken from [Hasegawa's and Lemay's paper](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/33/37/33-37.pdf)) is wrong, I am having trouble understanding the correspondence between (non-symmetric) $\ast$-autonomous categories and linearly distributive categories with negation. Maybe you can find my mistake in the following thoughts? My question whether the equality $\phi(r)=id ⅋ \phi(r)$  holds, stems precisely from trying to give a proof of that correspondence. Consider for instance the sketched proof on page 3 of Hasegawa and Lemay's paper ...

Comment: They call a category $\ast$-autonomous if it has (in your words) the *property* of being $\ast$-autonomous. While "proving" that star-autonomous categories admit a linearly distributive structure they however speak of "*the* natural bijection". Yet there is a choice of natural bijection involved (essentially since adjunction isomorphisms are only unique up to composing with automorphisms of the functors in the functor category in question) and a different choice can lead to diagrams commuting that did not commute before (see my answer on mathSe)...

Comment: Concretely: Given a $\ast$-autonomous category choose a natural bijection. Using the bijection one can define right and left distributors (do they depend on the choice of $\ast$-autonomous structure? Are there multiple choices of distributors possible?). When checking whether diagram (6) of linearly distributive categories commutes, I am lead to the equality from my question.

Comment: If the equality does not hold for all choices of $\phi$ then one would have to find different distributors or show that $\phi$ can always be chosen such that the equality holds.

Comment: By "a correct structure" I meant "a correct definition of $\ast$-autonomous structure".  The point is exactly that the isomorphism is not unique, i.e. a given monoidal category can admit many different $\ast$-autonomous structures.  (Although, your examples of different such isomorphisms for finite-dimensional vector spaces I would not regard as an example of this variety, since the nontrivial cases do not satisfy the pentagon axiom, so I would not call them $\ast$-autonomous structures.)

Comment: I believe that given an "incoherent" $\phi$ (not satisfying the pentagon) it is always possible to find a different $\phi$ that is coherent.  In fact I think that this is what happens if you start from an "incoherent $\ast$-autonomous structure", make it into a linearly distributive category with negation, and then come back to a $\ast$-autonomous structure.  (So I believe the HL claim that "these constructions are mutually inverse" is not true as stated, that you don't get back to the same $\phi$ if you started with an incoherent one.)

Comment: I have some notes for an incomplete paper I was writing a while ago on a question close to this one that I'd be happy to share if you send me an email.

Comment: Your comments make things clearer, thank you. Many thanks for offering to share your notes! I sent you an email. Hopefully your notes will make clearer what you mean by "coherent $\phi$".